# Find permanently installed physical drives using WMI

Tags: windows, wmi

I'm using WMI to find all the `Win32_DiskDrive`s on a machine.  I want to exclude drives temporarily installed, like USB drives.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can look at the `InterfaceType` property; this will give you "USB" for USB drives.  Unfortunately there is not really any reliable method to determine "temporarily installed".  There is nothing stopping somebody from permanently mounting a USB drive inside their computer, though this is of course extremely unlikely.  A more practical problem is that there is no way to determine whether a SATA drive is internal or external.

Comment: @Luke: thanks.  Excluding USB drives will likely fix most problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for USB devices using WMI like this:

```
public void CollectUSBDevices()
        {
            NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher2 = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM win32_pnpentity where deviceid like 'USB%'");
            // Iterate through all found USB objects.            
            foreach (ManagementObject dm in searcher2.Get())
            {
                string nameValue = dm["Name"].ToString();
                string devid = dm["DeviceID"].ToString();

                if (nameValue.Contains("Generic USB Hub") || nameValue.Contains("USB Root Hub"))
                    continue;

                if (nameValue.Contains("USB Mass Storage Device") || devid.Contains("USBSTOR\\"))
                    collection.Add("USBDevice", nameValue);
            }
        }
```